# Why doesn't direct path for delete/destroy exist in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, destroy, http-delete

When you define a link_to in rails to delete an object/item you must specify method delete in that link_to, as compared to edit (edit_event_path(@event)) or show (event_path). Why is this the case?

Comment: read up on REST http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typical link_to links the browser will send HTTP GET requests. When you're destroying a resource the browser should send a HTTP DELETE request. Rails has some javascript that will run on those links and intercept the click to send a HTTP DELETE request for those marked with method: :delete. Also the path for a single resource to be destroyed and shown will be the same.

event_path will return "/event/1" or similar. When sending a HTTP GET request its expected that the show action of your controller will be called. When sending a HTTP DELETE request to the *same* path its expected that the destroy action will be called.

Answer (score 1):

**HTTP Verbs**

Simply, Rails makes use of the [HTTP Verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) which governs the web

Essentially, to keep routing structures simple, Rails allows you to generate a series of the "same" URL paths, each defined with different `http verbs`:

[image]

This means if you want to `destroy` an object, you can use the `delete` verb

--

**OOP**

A more specific definition for this lies with the [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) structure of Ruby (& Rails). The routing system is based around this structure (hence why they're called `resources`) - meaning if you treat the routing system as based around *objects*, you can begin to see a pattern emerge

If you're going to call a `route` for an object, IE to `destroy` that object, your route should be for the "object", not the "destroy" mechanism

In this sense, if you want to destroy an object, it makes much more sense to use the following:

```
<%= link_to "Destroy", object_path(object), method: :delete %>
```

This gives you the flexibility to create actions *around* objects, which can then be routed to the particular controller#actions as required